# LyX 2.3.1 / MiKTeX / Windows 10 does not see was and upgreek packages

Tags: lyx, packages, miktex, greek

I'm trying to enter upright Greek letters into my equations using the `upgreek` package (which in turn is part of was – see [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/upgreek?lang=en)).

I'm using LyX 2.3.1 on Windows 10 with MiKTeX 2.9.

I installed the was package, and then updated my LaTeX preamble as follows:

```
\usepackage{was}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{upgreek}
```

Unfortunately, I don't see a vertical delta, for example, when I type `\updelta` into an equation. I have updated MiKTeX and reconfigured my LyX file, and also exited and restarted LyX, all to no avail.

What might I be doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you refresh the  FNBD?

Comment: You’re going to have to forgive me for asking, but what is FNBD and how do I refresh it?

Comment: If it’s any help I updated Miktex before downloading was and Reconfigured in LyX

Comment: It's an acronym for the File Names Data Base. You can do that  from MiKTeX Console, Tasks menu. Click on the corresponding item (both as user and as administrator).

Comment: Did you install `was` with MiKTeX package manager?

Comment: Yes I did, and I installed was as an administrator. I’m currently away from my computer but when I get back in about 3 hours I will update the file names database. Question: why do I have to do it as both a user and an administrator?

Comment: I always do like you, but it's recommended, I think, just in case you're not  connected as administrator. This being said, do you know the `newtx` package has a `frenchmath` option, which makes all Greek letters upshape (and also all  capital Latin letters upshape, as is traditional in French maths typography).

Comment: Never heard of newtx, but I will install it tonight. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: You'll have to load it in two parts: `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`. It iis based on the same times-clone as `tx `, with different metrics.

Comment: No luck - refreshing the file names database in MikTex and reconfiguring my LyX file, then saving it, exiting LyX and reopening it does not change anything \updelta still continues to be visible \updelta. Anything else I should be trying?

Comment: Try to export a small latex example so that we can see the real code. And try to compile the example with pdflatex so that you can show the log.